# Uncontrollable Cpu Fan BIOS

Tags: 18.04, asus, fan, fancontrol, motherboard

The speed of my CPU fan it's out of control, just go to the fastest speed to the lowes without any reason. The next list is the things that I have tried without any success:

1. I tried to change in the bios and set other parameters.
2. Install `sensors`, detect it, and install `fancontrol`
3. Reinstall Bios software and Ubuntu.
4. try other monitoring programs as `psensors, htop, tlp,` etc.

Are there anyway (programs, commands, whatever) to control my fan speed in Ubuntu, or to make my Bios work correctly. **in addition here is my hardware setup:**

- Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX X399-E GAMING
- Fan: cryorig a40 ultimate
- CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920x
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Also, I have to say, that I can see the fan speed with `sensors` or other monitoring software...

Comment: After a lot of reasearch, I think that all my problems comes from the bios, sometimes the bios can control de fan speed, others times not, honestly, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't control fan speed. It is controlled by BIOS.

Comment: Ubuntu can control the fan speeds...why else would there be `fancontrol`?  The last statement says that you CAN see the fan speeds in Ubuntu, correct?  If so, post the content of /etc/fancontrol